# Displaying data from URL into listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have created an app which fetches data from a URL using a JSON array request when I display the data from URL like this:

[image: it is like this]

how can I show this data in a listview? Here is my code:

```
public class JsonRequestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private String TAG = JsonRequestActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnJsonObj, btnJsonArray;
private TextView msgResponse;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// These tags will be used to cancel the requests
private String tag_json_obj = "jobj_req", tag_json_arry = "jarray_req";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);

    btnJsonObj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJsonObj);
    btnJsonArray = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJsonArray);
    msgResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgResponse);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    btnJsonObj.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnJsonArray.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.hide();
}

/**
 * Making json object request
 * */
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            Const.URL_JSON_OBJECT, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "Androidhive");
            params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
            params.put("pass", "password123");

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,
            tag_json_obj);

    // Cancelling request
    // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_obj);       
}

/**
 * Making json array request
 * */
private void makeJsonArryReq() {
    showProgressDialog();
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req,
            tag_json_arry);

    // Cancelling request
    // ApplicationController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().cancelAll(tag_json_arry);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnJsonObj:
        makeJsonObjReq();
        break;
    case R.id.btnJsonArray:
        makeJsonArryReq();
        break;
    }

}
```

}

And this is the URL I am using

```
http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_array.json
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What have you tried already? ListView isn't mentioned anywhere in your code.

Comment: i want suggestions for that like should i create custom layout for list view or another activity? and then where should i declare arraylist and how can i out url in arraylist to show it in listview

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad. Please search for articles and tutorials that explain how to implement the functionality you need, and come back if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
    "email": "ravi8x@gmail.com",
    "phone": {
      "home": "08947 000000",
      "mobile": "9999999999"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Tommy",
    "email": "tommy@gmail.com",
    "phone": {
      "home": "08946 000000",
      "mobile": "0000000000"
    }
  }
]
```

Here it is json array. You can parse it this way:

Create a java object class. Your class is like this:

Your Phone Entity is here:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class PhoneObject{
@SerializedName("home")
public String home;
@SerializedName("mobile")
 public String mobile;
}
```

Your User object is it:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class UserObject{
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("email")
public String email;

@SerializedName("phone")
public PhoneObject phone;

public UserObject(){
phone=new Phone();
}

}
```

Now in your `onResponse` callback use this line of code:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<UserObject>>() {}.getType();
List<UserObject> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), listType);
```

Now you have UserObject List in `yourList`. Next stage is create a ListView and initialize it. Create an adapter , set it's item layout and invalidate data of it's item.

Suppose your ListView is like this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#555"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="#000" />
```

and your list item row like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="8dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now Your Adapter will like this:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<UserObject> items;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context activity, List<UserObject> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return items.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        // getting movie data for the row
        UserObject m = items.get(position);

        name.setText(m.name);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Now you just call this way in `onResponse()` callback

```
CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, yourList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Edit: Why Java Object**

You have a json Array. It's individual object is like this:

```
{
        "name": "Ravi Tamada",
        "email": "ravi8x@gmail.com",
        "phone": {
          "home": "08947 000000",
          "mobile": "9999999999"
        }
      }
```

Here, it is a json object, it contains string's and tag's are "name", 'email', and an Json Object tag "phone".

So here this object contains some string and a json object name "phone".

From previous discussion, I created a Java Object name `PhoneObject` it's tag's are initialized using this way:

```
@SerializedName("home")
    public String home;
```

Now "phone" tag is in main Object. So i created `UserObject` and initialized `PhoneObject` in that object.

**Note:** You have to realize the json structure and after that you have to start creating the java object.

All are done. If need more information visit [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Comment: Thank you so much it looks like working but i am a bit confused in java object class how can i create? i mean write that code in my jsonr equest activity or should i create new java class for it?

Comment: @Ali , I edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: I understand everything but confused in java object class how can i create it? it is giving me an error and what is Gson and type token?

Comment: :) 
Gson is library that use to parse json. Read this article about Gson.
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Comment: sure. My id is mesuk08

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

helpful link : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 0):

You have to write some code for this.

- Parse JSON response and create object(you can use HashMap also).
- Create a layout file in xml for showing the items of list view.
- Create a custom adapter class and inflate the xml layout, get views and set the values to the views.
- set the adapter to your list view.

you can take help from below links:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html