# Json Parser Error - Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0

Tags: android, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm struggling with an issue while sending Json data to the server. I guess there is some issue with the bad characters which are not expected at start of UTF-8 format.

I used CharDecoder to replace all the malformed utf-8 characters and here is the code.

```
 // Construct the Decoder
    CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
    utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
    utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
    //  Configure to replace Malformed input with space
    utf8Decoder.replaceWith(" ");

    //  Construct ByteBuffer
    ByteBuffer byteBuff = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getBytes());
    try {
        //  Process the text.
        CharBuffer parsed = utf8Decoder.decode(byteBuff);
        return new String(parsed.array());
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is not helping me. When I look at the column line of Json post data where parser is complaining, it is a space character.

Json to post is

```
{"body":{"messageSegments":[{"type":"Text","text":"This is a link "},{"type":"Mention","id":"005GGGGGG02g6MMIAZ"},{"type":"Text","text":" ish"}]},"capabilities":{"questionAndAnswers":{"questionTitle":"https:\/\/www.google.co.nz\/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&amp;amp;amp;amp;ion=1&amp;amp;amp;amp;espv=2&amp;amp;amp;amp;ie=UTF-16"}}}
```

Error is

**`[{"errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR","message":"Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0 at [line:1, column:139]"}]`**

Any leads please.

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: you are fetching error to parse response. You can use Volley and Gson to call Rest API. Here is similar example
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37242140/3073945

Comment: Im using salesforce Mobile SDK, So I have not freedom to use other NW libraries. But Salesforce is internally using Volley library. Thanks..

Comment: see this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573994/jackson-jackson-httppost-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte-setting-mime-and-enco

Answer (score 2):

0xa0 is a Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0)

not the usual space 0x20

visually hard to notice the difference, but some frameworks do not like it.

Comment: Note that 'NO-BREAK SPACE' in UTF-8 is two bytes: 0xc2 0xa0: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x 

I cannot find plain 0xA0 in UTF-8, which makes sense if it's not a valid start byte.

Answer (score 1):

Convert characters `-` the other characters and test it.

Helpful link http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt